Distinction between Hypoxia and Hypoxaemia
I have heard two different sets of definitions of hypoxia and hypoxaemia. I am finding it difficult to consolidate them; I am not sure that the two sets of definitions are consistent with each other.
One of them is that hypoxia is low partial pressure of oxygen, whereas hypoxaemia is low oxygen content. According to this definition, low haemoglobin would result in hypoxaemia, but not hypoxia.
The other equates the partial pressure of oxygen with oxygen content: hypoxaemia is low partial pressure or low concentration, and hypoxia is inadequate tissue oxygenation. In this definition, hypoxia is dependent on the oxygen content, the delivery of oxygenated blood and the extraction of oxygen in the tissues.
I figure that the two sets of definitions can be at least partially consolidated.
The diffusion of oxygen into the tissues is dependent on partial pressure, and not directly on saturation.
But I'm not all that confident in that assessment, and I am not sure how to think about hypoxia and hypoxaemia.
Is one of these sets of definitions more correct than the other? Is it a case of scientists using one set while clinicians use another, or a case of different clinical specialties using different definitions?
Both sets were given in a respiratory lecture context, by two different lecturers, and they have left me a bit confused.

You're on the right track in your 3rd paragraph. "-emia" refers to blood specifically: anemia, septicemia, methemoglobinemia, leukemia, etc. One measures hypoxemia through arterial blood sampling. It can be inferred, though. Hypoxia is a decrease in tissue O2. Often caused by hypoxemia, could be localized (e.g. stroke, MI, etc.) 2° to decreased blood supply. The different specialists don't treat the terms differently; doctors treat the "cause" of hypoxia (which isn't always hypoxemia, e.g. with thrombolytics), while some address the specific causes of hypoxemia (e.g. ARDS).

It's like the difference between septicemia and sepsis. As clinicians, we usually treat sepsis, but order blood cultures to detect septicemia.

Are you sure both were using "hypoxia"? The first definition sounds closer to what is meant by hypoxic to me.

From Hypoxia on Stat Pearls:

Hypoxia occurs when oxygen is insufficient at the tissue level to maintain adequate homeostasis, stemming from various causes. This condition can arise from inadequate oxygen delivery to the tissues due to either low blood supply (ischemia) or low oxygen content in the blood, also known as hypoxemia.

So hypoxaemia is one cause of tissue hypoxia. Reduced blood supply is another cause, which could be due to thromboembolism, blood loss causing reduced blood volume, reduced perfusion due to vasodilation (such as in sepsis) or narrowed vessels due to atherosclerosis.
In turn there are multiple causes of hypoxemia, such as reduced partial pressure of oxygen in inhaled air (such as at altitude), impaired gas exchange in the lungs (due to a host of different conditions including pneumonia), or right-to-left shunting due to congenital heart disease (where the lungs are bypassed).
